# Pycharm debugger: breakpoint links to remote_source files

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While using the pycharm debugger breakpoints are linking to copies of files saved in remote_sources,
`C:\Users\me\.PyCharm2019.2\system\remote_sources\921495913\41753927\pipeline.py`
rather than reading the correct project file. `C:\Users\me\project\pipeline.py`.

The problem occurred after I had updated some python packages (pandas, pytest). Not sure if it is related.

I have my root set to `C:\Users\me\project\` and WSL mapping `C:\Users\me\project\` to `/mnt/c/Users/me/project`. These have not changed and have been working fine in the past.

I am using Pycharm professional 2019.2, Windows 10 running Ubuntu with WSL and have WSL remote interpreter configured in Pycharm.

How can I remove the link to `\.PyCharm2019.2\system\remote_sources\` and debug on local files as I always have in the past?

Comment: This is a known issue: [WSL interpreter uses outdated files in remote_sources when debugging installed (editable) package](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40581)